# Bash variable does not allow a directory name to be assigned to it

Tags: bash, directory

I want to create the following variable in Bash:

```
PATHTOMYDIR=/fshare/users/myusername/
```

(basically, a variable with a string inside: the path to my directory, where I have my data, that later on can be included in some scripts to generate folders inside that directory, for example).

The concrete problem is: when I typed that line of code I got the following error message:

```
-bash: /fshare/users/myusername: Is a directory
```

Hence, I wanted to ask: does Bash not allow a variable to contain the name of a path? I thought it was possible, so I assume I am missing something else here. I googled the error message but I did not find any post at any forum with this case.

Comment: Please include your code here so we can try it out. I can do `x=/a/dir/I/have` without issue.

Comment: Agreed.  That code looks good.  I believe your error would be replicated if it were `PATHTOMYDIR= /fshare/users/myusername/` (with a space after the "=").

Comment: You are both right! I had a space between the "=" and the first "/" of the path. It seems that space makes the difference. Something simple, but it is ok to leave it here in case someone else has the same problem (specially when you're a rookie). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a space between the "=" and the first "/" of the path.

This makes an error:

```
PATHTOMYDIR= /fshare/users/myusername/
```

This is correct:

```
PATHTOMYDIR=/fshare/users/myusername/
```

It seems that space makes the difference. Thank you @AIG and @Jason !

EDIT: @Jason pointed out that is good practice to use commas, so a more correct form would be:

```
PATHTOMYDIR="/fshare/users/myusername/"
```

Comment: By the way, it is good practice to quote variables like this. In the future, if this directory were to have a space in it, it would break your code. `PATHTOMYDIR="/fshare/users/myusername/"`